# Need to put a RadioButton against each Row in a DataGrid view in a Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I need to put a  RadioButton against each Row in a DataGrid view . But Iam unable to find a  control like DataGridViewRadioButtonColumn just like DataGridViewTextBoxColumn . So how should I go about doing it ? Thanks in Advance
(User can only select one radio button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your own custom Cell and Column to implement this functionality.

There is an [excellent article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882%28VS.80%29.aspx) that describes this scenario almost exactly. It shows you how to create a custom radio button cell that supports multiple radio buttons per cell. The code could easily be adapted to allow just one radio button per cell.

The article is written for Visual Studio 2005, but should work equally well for VS2008 and VS2010.

Comment: well, the article talks about adding radio buttons inside a data grid view cell. But that will definitely give me some direction ..Thanks Jazza.

Comment: @Ananth: yes it does; the code in the article allows for you to specify how many radio buttons per cell, and shows how the custom cell can be put in a custom column to get you the functionality you require.